# Suppress specific warning message in mysql

Tags: mysql

Is there a mysql config to suppress a specific warning message? For a particular legacy code I'm stuck using an older mysql client which results in the warning:

`[Warning] [MY-013360] [Server] Plugin mysql_native_password reported: ''mysql_native_password' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use caching_sha2_password instead'`

There isn't really a way for me to work around using the old password scheme - is there a way to simply suppress this particular warning message from firing?

Comment: if you have the legacy mode enable during configuration, or by  using reconfigure, you don't gezt the message

Comment: @nbk do you know what setting the "legacy mode" would be, like a flag/variable name? I did some searching and only found `default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password` which I've already set

Comment: when you install the server you can set the legacy mode, but when you use the mysql installer you can reconfigure the server instance , where you can enable it

Comment: any idea the specific server variable/option flag for "legacy mode". I can't seem to find?

Answer (score 2):

Not the solution for targeting a specific error, but to suppress warnings in general, the following in mysql.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
log_error_verbosity=1
```

will have change to output only ERROR-level

Comment: On the command line this looks like: `mysqld --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password --log_error_verbosity=1`